# If $p-1$ and $p+1$ are twin primes, and $p>4$, prove that $3\varphi(p)\le p$.

Tags: number-theory

If $p-1$ and $p+1$ are twin primes, and $p>4$, prove that $3\varphi(p)\le p$.

I am stuck on this and don't have clue how to tackle this.

Comment: $p$ is not prime? I hate this choice of notation.

Comment: Hint – $p$ is a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider mod 6. It would help to know the explicit formula for $\phi$ but you can reason through it either way.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if  $p > 4$ then $p$  must be a multiple of $6$.

So $p = 2^a\cdots3^b\cdot m$, $ab \ge 1, \Longrightarrow (m, 6) = 1$.

Since $\varphi(p)$ is a multiplicative function, we have,

$\varphi(p)$ = $\varphi(2^a)\cdots\varphi(3^{b}) \varphi (m)$

We also know that for any prime number $l$, $\varphi(l^k$) = $l^k$ - $l^{k-1}$ = $l^{k-1}(l-1)$,  and that  $\varphi(l^k$) $\le l^k$

$\Longrightarrow\varphi(2^a).\varphi(3^b)$ = $2^{a-1}\cdot(2-1)\cdot3^{b-1}(3-1)$ = $2^a.3^{b-1}$

Therefore, we have $\varphi(p) \le 2^a\cdot3^{b-1} \varphi (m) \le 2^a\cdot3^{b-1} m = p/3$.

Comment: Since you are using a regular (lower) dot in order to terminate each sentence, I suggest that you use a "$\cdot$" (\cdot) in order to denote multiplication.

Comment: Keeping it in mind is nice, but I suggest that you also apply it into the text (because it will not be visible otherwise).

Comment: "\cdot", not "\cdots".

Comment: I'm not sure if this proof is correct. The reasoning in the last line does not seem how phi(6) works.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a few more details to make it clear